# How to use findViewById to get a ListView

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-listview, findviewbyid

I don't know why this code is using findViewById to get the list view.  Isn't the list view native to the ContentView that I set earlier?  If not how do I set up a ListView for that Content View?  I really just want to know if the setting up of the list view is necessary.

```
setContentView(R.layout.imgp_activity_home);
final String[] values = new String[] {"No Docs", "Pending", "Processed"};

final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.???);

final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i<values.length; i++) {
    list.add(values[i]);
```

...

```
listview.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapter);
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
```

...
I feel like I should be able to add the listener to the array list somehow.

This is the tutorial I used to get me [started](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html).

Comment: use 

final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

Comment: @Sam could answer this well. But I believe that one is created automatically if you don't specify one, although I always create one so not entirely sure how that works. But declaring it yourself gives you more flexibility over the style and other attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in you layout floder about the activity layout the XML file called imgp_activity_home.xml.in this file you may have the tags about＜listview＞. set tags like ＜listview android:id="@+id/listname"＞.then in the Java file you can findviewbyid(r.id.listname).if you didn't declare the listview tag.you must new a listview object in you code.

Comment: Please try to edit and make your answer clearer or more readily understood.

Answer (score 0):

From the example you should write

```
final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the question properly. I believe the OP knows how to do this but is asking if it is necessary.